# For which of the following will a hash table be best to solve the problem?

Tags: algorithm, performance, big-o, hashtable

Will a hash table be a good solution for either of those?

> Determining if two of the workers in the factory have identical names, assuming we are given a list that is unsorted and contains their names. The list will contain n workers.

> Get a list that is in sorted order, assuming we are given a list that is unsorted and contains all of the workers' names. The list will contain n workers.

First, I tried reasoning through both statements using the worst, best, and average cases.
For the first option, I noticed that we can have a hashtable that is implemented using linear probing. In which case, we will have to iterate over the list of the workers, add them to our hashtable, and if we get a conflict, stop iterating right away. This led me to state that the worst case will be O(n) and average-case and the best case will be O(1).

For the second option, I could not think of a way to complete it which led me to think that a hash table would not make sense for that problem.

So, I concluded that the first problem would be perfectly fine to be solved using a hash table, while the other not. Does this sound right?

Comment: I assume your question is, given a list of names, find out if there are any duplicates. You are given two options, a hash table, and sorting after? Both have various considerations.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the first part of your question:

> Determining if two of the workers in the factory have identical names,
> assuming we are given a list that is unsorted and contains their
> names. The list will contain n workers.

Yes hash table is a good solution for this problem. However, you will need a good hashing function. You can use `polynomial rolling hash function`. Here is a link for more information on hashing strings.

https://cp-algorithms.com/string/string-hashing.html

The problem with hashing is the ***space it requires*** and checking for ***hash collisions***. I suggest you follow Tony's advice he gave in the comments on testing hash functions.

Comment: _"first implement the hash function and test it using random inputs"_ - this is at best poorly and ambiguous worded and potentially misleading... truly random inputs (like a bunch of random letters or numbers) tend to be relatively uniformly distributed across hash table buckets even with a pathetically weak or even an identity hash function.  You should test with the same - or failing that similar - inputs to what you'll be hashing in actual usage, so in this case - perhaps a bunch of (possibly randomly selected) names from a telephone book.  I hope the latter is what you intended to say.

Comment: @TonyDelroy Thank you for the suggestion. I will improve my answer. I will keep this in mind when answering future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right.  In both cases, your input in an unsorted list of workers' names, which you could insert one-by-one into a hash table with O(1) average efficiency if your hash function was vaguely reasonable.  Then, which functions could the hash table reasonably support:

> Determining if two of the workers in the factory have identical names

This would have been obvious during insertion: you'd have found the name already in the hash table.  You wouldn't even need to continue inserting further names if you just needed to know if there was one case.

> Get a list that is in sorted order

There's no way you can traverse a hash table in sorted order, so you'd have to extract the values from the hash table.  Reasonable options include copying them into an array then sort that in-place, and copying them into a balanced binary tree - which would keep them sorted as they were inserted and the tree was rebalanced.  If you were going to use an array or balanced binary tree, you might as well have inserted names directly into that container: the hash table step would be a waste of time.